# Images won't stretch to fit within grid/column

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to figure out why the images wont stretch to fit the columns and widths I've set them to. There is a lot of empty space as you can see by the pictures. I've tried object-fit: cover which works well with background images, but I don't know how to get it to work here. It seems like if the image is larger vertically I can't seem to position it horizontally across a couple columns and vice versa. Yet, I'm struggling to achieve a layout in a 4x4 grid where I have grid template areas set the way I want them to be.

[image: my issue]
[image: my issue]

what I want to achieve is this image or to at least understand why i cant get this stretch effect on the images so I can customize the grid to my liking, I've even set the images dimensions exactly the same, and nothing has changed. The grid seems to be a different width and height than mine despite being repeat(4,1fr) for both grid-template-columns and rows.

```
.picture_grid{
    max-width: 90vw;
    margin:2rem auto;
}

.food_title{
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 6rem;
}

.food_title:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    background: #F4D06F;
    width: 15rem;
    height: 0.25rem;;
}

img{max-width:80%;
    height:auto}

.food_picture{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}



.pic_1{
    grid-area: one;
}

.pic_2{
    grid-area: two;
}
.pic_3{
    grid-area: three;
}

.pic_4{
    grid-area: four;
}

.pic_5{
    grid-area: five;
}

.pic_6{
    grid-area: six;
}

.pic_7{
    grid-area: seven;
}

.pic_8{
    grid-area: eight;
}


@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
    .picture_grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width:992px) {

    .picture_grid {
        height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4,1fr);
  grid-template-areas: 
  "one one two three"
  "one one four four"
  "five six seven seven"
  "eight nine seven seven"
    }

  }
```

```
<section class="our_work">
<h2 class="food_title">Our Food</h2>

<div class="picture_grid">
<article class="food_picture pic_1">
  <img src="img/food_1.jpg" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
  <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="1">
  </a>
</article>

<article class="food_picture pic_2">
  <img src="img/food_2.jpg" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
  <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="2">
  </a>
</article>

<article class="food_picture pic_3">
  <img src="img/food_3.jpg" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
  <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="3">
  </a>
</article>

<article class="food_picture pic_4">
  <img src="img/food_4.jpg" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
  <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="4">
  </a>
</article>

<article class="food_picture pic_5">
  <img src="img/food_5.jpg" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
  <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="5">
  </a>
</article>

<article class="food_picture pic_6">
  <img src="img/food_6.jpg" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
  <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="6">
  </a>
</article>

<article class="food_picture pic_7">
  <img src="img/food_7.jpg" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
  <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="7">
  </a>
</article>

<article class="food_picture pic_8">
  <img src="img/food_8.jpg" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
  <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="8">
  </a>
</article>

</div>

</section>
```

Comment: Can you add your html

Comment: It's always helpful if we can reproduce this in it's entirety via an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), though at a glance I'd guess your `img` needs to be 100% h/w with `object-fit:cover`

Comment: if your element is to fill 2 column grid, it has to be spanning two columns and or be set to 100% width. Your css, missing the html, doesn't for sure,  tell this.

Comment: added html, as I said in the OP I tried object fit: cover......

Answer (score 2):

Why are you setting `img{max-width:80%; ...`? Not sure if I understand your intended goal correctly, but if you set both `width` and `height` of the image to `100%`, the images get stretched...probably not ideal as they will look strange (if you don't crop them to an exact ratio). Another option could be to have them as `background-image` and use `background-size: cover`, then they would get "cropped" by the browser but still keep the ratio.

*PS: Edited your breakpoint so we can see it in the snippet result directly here on SO*

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.picture_grid {
    max-width: 90vw;
    margin: 2rem auto;
}

.food_title {
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 6rem;
}
.food_title:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    background: #F4D06F;
    width: 15rem;
    height: 0.25rem;
}

img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: 1px solid gray;
}

.food_picture {
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}

.pic_1 {
    grid-area: one;
}

.pic_2 {
    grid-area: two;
}
.pic_3 {
    grid-area: three;
}

.pic_4 {
    grid-area: four;
}

.pic_5 {
    grid-area: five;
}

.pic_6 {
    grid-area: six;
}

.pic_7 {
    grid-area: seven;
}

.pic_8 {
    grid-area: eight;
}
@media screen and (min-width:320px) {
    .picture_grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:600px) {

    .picture_grid {
        height: 100vh;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(4,1fr);
        grid-template-areas: "one one two three" "one one four four" "five six seven seven" "eight nine seven seven";
    }

}
```

```html
<section class="our_work">
 <h2 class="food_title">Our Food</h2>
 
 <div class="picture_grid">
  <article class="food_picture pic_1">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
   <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="1">
   </a>
  </article>
  
  <article class="food_picture pic_2">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
   <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="2">
   </a>
  </article>
  
  <article class="food_picture pic_3">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
   <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="3">
   </a>
  </article>
  
  <article class="food_picture pic_4">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
   <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="4">
   </a>
  </article>
  
  <article class="food_picture pic_5">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
   <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="5">
   </a>
  </article>
  
  <article class="food_picture pic_6">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
   <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="6">
   </a>
  </article>
  
  <article class="food_picture pic_7">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
   <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="7">
   </a>
  </article>
  
  <article class="food_picture pic_8">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600" alt="" class="food_picture_img">
   <a href="#" class="food_picture_icon" data-id="8">
   </a>
  </article>
  
 </div>
 
</section>
```

Comment: Ok, i found the problem, if I set width and height to 100% for the img class "food_picture" it does not change it. But if i set img width:100%; height:100%; it works perfectly. Little things like this make css quite agonizing.

Comment: just what I wrote above, right? =) an image always keeps its aspect ratio if you don't tell it otherwise! I honestly think it would be much more agonzing if CSS would "fit" images to whatever the parent container's size is...imagine that!

Comment: thanks man, ya but its weird why the image class wouldnt affect the image settings X_X. Any suggestions on where to read up on how to make the grid fit images nicely, preserving aspect ratios and fitting it within the grid template areas I want. it seems like the problems comes from images having different height and width dimensions, and trying to fit them into different area spaces, causes them to stretch in ways I dont want, object-fit: cover worked now, but it crops some images too.

Comment: the `.food_picture` class does NOT target the image, it targets the container, if you wanted to target the image you need to use `.food_picture_img` but you do not use that, instead you target the `img` tag directly with our styles.